# Where do I specify product using Stripe payments?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm implementing Stripe for payments which are subscriptions to my SaaS app.

Stripe, recently asked me to make sure I'm using their latest API which has the concept of products.

My question, where do I specify the product? In the `StripeCustomerCreateOptions` during customer creation or `StripeChargeCreateOptions` during the charge?

I don't see a ProductId in either object -- btw, I'm using the `.NET Client`.

However, in `StripeCustomerCreateOptions` object, I do see `PlanId` as well as `Quantity` properties. I sell "licenses" for my SaaS app which are monthly subscriptions. So a customer may pay for 3 monthly subscription licenses.

Do I specify the product through the `PlanId` and set the quantity in `StripeCustomerCreateOptions`, then simply set the total amount in the `StripeChargeCreateOptions`?

Is this how I'm supposed to handle my charges using Stripe?

Comment: Are you trying to create `Subscriptions` or one-off `Charges` here --- for subscriptions:  you create a `Product` and attach `Plans` to it. You attach a `Plan` when creating a `Subscription` --- see https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart#define-plan

If you're making one-off charges you don't use any of this, simply charge the Customer. https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards

Comment: I'm trying to create a subscription. So if I'm following you correctly, I then use the `PlanId` under `StripeCustomerCreateOptions` to specify the subscription plan for that particular customer, correct?